# Wubi took up all of my disk space on Win 7

Tags: wubi, live-usb, disk

I tried to create a live 13.04 USB using a 1TB external hard drive and it wouldn't boot on my machine. After that, I booted into windows and tried to run Wubi from the hard drive and I selected the "help me boot from CD" option. When it was at the stage of copying the files and it copied way more than it should have and now I only have about 200MB left on windows. Can anyone please tell me if this is reversible? All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write an ISO to a USB drive, the ISO "size" is the size of the USB partition. When you then install Wubi from that USB, it will copy the entire partition as if it were the ISO.

e.g. a USB key that is 4 GB, then the `C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso` file will be 4 GB. If you happened to have a 32 GB USB, then it will attempt to copy 32 GB.

Note that this will fail anyway, because Wubi checks the ISO size later. But the fact is it was originally written expecting CDs or DVDs and it doesn't handle USBs in a logical way.

So, go find and delete the `C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso` file (if you can't boot Windows) or uninstall *Ubuntu* from the Control panel and it will free up that space.